# Univariate analysis with SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, statistics, postgresql, stored-procedure, plpgsql

I wrote a *SQL univariate analysis stored procedure* taking as input a schemaname and a tablename on PostgreSQL. It is exactly like a PROC SAS UNIVARIATE. As output, you get less than 20 usable statistical metrics.

There are 4 big parts in this code:

**Part 1:**
Create the right schemas and populate the data table:
Tests have been done on the famous dataset iris from statisticians:

```
begin ;

Create Schema If Not Exists data ;
Create Schema If Not Exists stat ;

Create Table If Not Exists data.iris
(
      SepalLength Float
    , SepalWidth  Float
    , PetalLength Float
    , PetalWidth  Float
    , Species     Character Varying
)
;

INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.8,1.5,0.3,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.8,3.1,1.6,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.2,4.1,1.5,0.1,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.2,1.2,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.5,3.5,1.3,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.4,3.0,1.3,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.4,1.5,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.5,1.3,0.3,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.5,1.6,0.6,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.8,1.9,0.4,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.8,3.0,1.4,0.3,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,3.8,1.6,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,3.3,4.7,1.6,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.9,2.4,3.3,1.0,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.6,2.9,4.6,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.2,2.7,3.9,1.4,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,2.0,3.5,1.0,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.0,2.2,4.0,1.0,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.6,2.9,3.6,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.6,3.0,4.5,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.6,2.5,3.9,1.1,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.9,3.2,4.8,1.8,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.1,2.8,4.0,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,2.5,4.9,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.1,2.8,4.7,1.2,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.4,2.9,4.3,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.6,3.0,4.4,1.4,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.8,2.8,4.8,1.4,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,3.0,5.0,1.7,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.0,2.9,4.5,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,2.6,3.5,1.0,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.5,2.4,3.7,1.0,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.0,2.7,5.1,1.6,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.4,3.0,4.5,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.0,3.4,4.5,1.6,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,3.1,4.7,1.5,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,2.3,4.4,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.6,3.0,4.1,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.5,2.5,4.0,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.1,3.0,4.6,1.4,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.8,2.6,4.0,1.2,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.0,2.3,3.3,1.0,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.6,2.7,4.2,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,3.0,4.2,1.2,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,'Iris-versicolor');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.5,3.0,5.8,2.2,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.6,3.0,6.6,2.1,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 4.9,2.5,4.5,1.7,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.3,2.9,6.3,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,2.5,5.8,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.2,3.6,6.1,2.5,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.5,3.2,5.1,2.0,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.4,2.7,5.3,1.9,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.8,3.0,5.5,2.1,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.7,2.5,5.0,2.0,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.8,2.8,5.1,2.4,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.4,3.2,5.3,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.5,3.0,5.5,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.7,3.8,6.7,2.2,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.7,2.6,6.9,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.0,2.2,5.0,1.5,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.9,3.2,5.7,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.6,2.8,4.9,2.0,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.7,2.8,6.7,2.0,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,2.7,4.9,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,3.3,5.7,2.1,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.2,3.2,6.0,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.2,2.8,4.8,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.1,3.0,4.9,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.4,2.8,5.6,2.1,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.2,3.0,5.8,1.6,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.4,2.8,6.1,1.9,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.9,3.8,6.4,2.0,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.4,2.8,5.6,2.2,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,2.8,5.1,1.5,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.1,2.6,5.6,1.4,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 7.7,3.0,6.1,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,3.4,5.6,2.4,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.0,3.0,4.8,1.8,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.9,3.1,5.4,2.1,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,3.1,5.6,2.4,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.9,3.1,5.1,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.8,3.2,5.9,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,3.3,5.7,2.5,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.7,3.0,5.2,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.3,2.5,5.0,1.9,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 6.2,3.4,5.4,2.3,'Iris-virginica');
INSERT INTO data.iris VALUES( 5.9,3.0,5.1,1.8,'Iris-virginica');



commit ;
```

**Part 2:**
A result TEMP TABLE: __UNIVARIATE__

```
Drop Table If Exists __UNIVARIATE__ Cascade ;
Create Temporary Table __UNIVARIATE__
(
    "TimeStamp"    TIMESTAMP( 6) WITH TIME ZONE ,
    "DatabaseName" VARCHAR( 63) ,
    "SchemaName"   VARCHAR( 63) ,
    "TableName"    VARCHAR( 63) ,
    "ColumnName"   VARCHAR( 63) ,

    "N w Null"  BIGINT ,
    "N"         BIGINT ,
    "1/N"       FLOAT ,
    "N-1"       BIGINT ,

    "Min"  FLOAT ,
    "Max"  FLOAT ,

    "Avg"     FLOAT ,
    "Avgx 2"  FLOAT ,
    "Avgx 3"  FLOAT ,
    "Avgx 4"  FLOAT ,

    "Sum"     FLOAT ,
    "Sum x2"  FLOAT ,
    "Sum x3"  FLOAT ,
    "Sum x4"  FLOAT ,

    "Uniq" BIGINT ,
    "0"    BIGINT ,
    "POS"  BIGINT ,
    "NEG"  BIGINT ,
    "Null" BIGINT ,

    "Geometric Mean" FLOAT ,
    "Harmonic Mean"  FLOAT ,

    "Range" FLOAT ,
    "Mid-range" FLOAT ,

    "Kurtosis" FLOAT ,
    "Skewness" FLOAT ,

    "Perc Uniq"        FLOAT ,
    "Perc Uniq w Null" FLOAT ,
    "Perc 0"           FLOAT ,
    "Perc POS"         FLOAT ,
    "Perc NEG"         FLOAT ,
    "Perc Null"        FLOAT ,

    "Corrected Sum of Squares" FLOAT ,
    "Student Test Statistic"   FLOAT ,

    "Standard Deviation Population" FLOAT ,
    "Standard Deviation Sample"     FLOAT ,
    "Variance Population"           FLOAT ,
    "Variance Sample"               FLOAT ,

    "Coefficient Variation"         FLOAT ,

    "Sturges" FLOAT ,
    "Rice"    FLOAT ,
    "Sqrt"    FLOAT ,
    "Doane"   FLOAT ,
    "Scott"   FLOAT
)
On Commit Preserve Rows
;
```

**Part 3:** A View that creates a subset of queries doing the stat job per columns/table/schema/database. This is based on: information_schema.columns

```
Drop View If Exists stat.__QBUILDER_UNIVARIATE__ Cascade ;
Create Or Replace View stat.__QBUILDER_UNIVARIATE__
AS
Select
      table_catalog AS "DatabaseName"
    , table_schema  AS "SchemaName"
    , table_name    AS "TableName"
    , ROW_NUMBER() Over ( Partition By table_catalog, table_schema, table_name Order By table_name) AS RN
    , ' Select ' ||
            'Current_Timestamp( 6 ) AS "TimeStamp" ' ||
            ', Cast( '''|| col.table_catalog ||''' AS Varchar(63) ) AS "DatabaseName" ' ||
            ', Cast( '''|| col.table_schema ||''' AS Varchar(63) ) AS "SchemaName" ' ||
            ', Cast( '''|| col.table_name ||''' AS Varchar(63) ) AS "TableName" ' ||
            ', Cast( '''|| col.column_name ||''' AS Varchar(63) ) AS "ColumnName" ' ||
            ', t.* ' ||
        'From ' ||
        '( ' ||
            'Select ' ||
                't.* ' ||
                ', "Max" - "Min" AS "Range" ' ||
                ', ( "Max" + "Min" ) / 2 AS "Mid-range" ' ||
                ', ( ' ||
                        '( ' ||
                            '( ' ||
                                '"1/N" * "Sum x4" ' ||
                            '- ' ||
                                '4 * "Avg" * "Sum x3" * "1/N" ' ||
                            '+ ' ||
                                '6 * "Avgx 2" * ( ( "Sum x2" - "N" * "Avgx 2" ) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ) ' ||
                            ') ' ||
                            '+ ' ||
                            '3 * "Avgx 4" ' ||
                        ') ' ||
                        '/ ' ||
                        'NULLIF( ' ||
                            'Power( ' ||
                                'SQRT( ' ||
                                    'Case ' ||
                                        'When ( "Sum x2" - "N" * "Avgx 2" ) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                                        'Then ( "Sum x2" - "N" * "Avgx 2" ) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 )' ||
                                        'Else NULL ' ||
                                    'End ' ||
                                ') ' ||
                            ', 4 ) ' ||
                        ', 0 ) ' ||
                    ') ' ||
                '- ' ||
                    '( ' ||
                        '( 3 * Power( NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ), 2 ) ) ' ||
                        '/ ' ||
                        'NULLIF( ( NULLIF( "N", 2 ) -2 ) * ( NULLIF( "N", 3 ) -3 ), 0 ) ' ||
                    ') ' ||
                'AS "Kurtosis" ' ||
                ', ( ' ||
                    '"1/N" * "Sum x3" - "Avgx 3" - 3 * "Avg" * ( ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" ) ) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ) ' ||
                ') ' ||
                '/ ' ||
                'NULLIF( ' ||
                    'Power( ' ||
                        'SQRT( ' ||
                            'Case ' ||
                                'When ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) ' ||
                                '/ ' ||
                                'NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                                'Then ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) ' ||
                                '/ ' ||
                                'NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ),- 1 ) ' ||
                            'Else ' ||
                                'NULL ' ||
                            'End ' ||
                            ') ' ||
                    ', 3 ) ' ||
                ', 0 ) ' ||
                'AS "Skewness" ' ||
                ', "Uniq" / Cast( "N" AS Float ) * 100 AS "Perc Uniq" ' ||
                ', "Uniq" / Cast( "N w Null" AS Float ) * 100 AS "Perc Uniq w Null" ' ||
                ', "0" / Cast( "N" AS Float ) * 100 AS "Perc 0" ' ||
                ', "POS" / Cast( "N" AS Float ) * 100 AS "Perc POS" ' ||
                ', "NEG" / Cast( "N" AS Float ) * 100 AS "Perc NEG" ' ||
                ',"Null" / Cast( "N w Null" AS Float ) * 100 AS "Perc Null" ' ||
                ', "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" ) AS "Corrected Sum of Squares" ' ||
                ', ( "Avg" - 0 ) ' ||
                    '/ ' ||
                    'NULLIF( ' ||
                        '( ' ||
                            'SQRT( ' ||
                                'Case ' ||
                                    'When ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                                    'Then ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ' ||
                                    'Else NULL ' ||
                                'End ' ||
                            ') '||
                            '/ ' ||
                            'NULLIF( SQRT( Case When "N" >= 0 Then "N" Else NULL End ), 0 ) ' ||
                        ') ' ||
                    ', 0 ) ' ||
                'AS "Student Test Statistic" ' ||
                ', SQRT( ' ||
                    'Case ' ||
                        'When ( "Sum x2" -( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( "N", 0 ) >= 0 ' ||
                        'Then ( "Sum x2" -( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( "N", 0 ) ' ||
                        'Else NULL ' ||
                    'End ' ||
                ') AS "Standard Deviation Population" ' ||
                ', SQRT( ' ||
                    'Case ' ||
                        'When ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                        'Then ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ' ||
                        'Else NULL ' ||
                    'End ' ||
                ') AS "Standard Deviation Sample" ' ||
                ', ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" ) ) / NULLIF( "N", 0 ) AS "Variance Population" ' ||
                ', ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" ) ) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) AS "Variance Sample" ' ||
                ', SQRT( ' ||
                    'Case ' ||
                        'When ( "Sum x2" - "N" * "Avgx 2" ) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                        'Then ( "Sum x2" - "N" * "Avgx 2" ) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ' ||
                        'Else NULL ' ||
                    'End ' ||
                    ') ' ||
                '/ ' ||
                    'NULLIF( "Avg", 0 ) AS "Coefficient Variation" ' ||
                ', ( 1 + 10 / Cast( 3 AS Float ) * LOG( Case When "N" > 0 Then "N" Else NULL End ) ) AS "Sturges" ' ||
                ', ( 2 * Power( "N",( 1 / Cast( 3 AS Float ))) ) AS "Rice" ' ||
                ', ( SQRT( Case When "N" >= 0 Then "N" Else NULL End ) ) AS "Sqrt" ' ||
                ', ( 1 + ( LOG( Case When "N" > 0 Then "N" Else NULL End ) / LOG( 2 ) ) ' ||
                '+ ' ||
                '( ' ||
                    'LOG( ' ||
                        'Case ' ||
                            'When 1 + ' ||
                                '( ' ||
                                    '( "1/N" * "Sum x3" - "Avgx 3" - 3 * "Avg" * (( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ))) ' ||
                                    '/ ' ||
                                    'NULLIF( ' ||
                                        'Power( ' ||
                                            'SQRT( ' ||
                                                'Case ' ||
                                                    'When( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                                                    'Then( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ' ||
                                                    'Else NULL ' ||
                                                'End ' ||
                                            ') ' ||
                                        ', 3 ) ' ||
                                    ', 0 ) ' ||
                                ') > 0 ' ||
                            'Then 1 + ' ||
                                '( ' ||
                                    '( "1/N" * "Sum x3" - "Avgx 3" - 3 * "Avg" * (( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ))) ' ||
                                    '/ ' ||
                                    'NULLIF( ' ||
                                        'Power( ' ||
                                            'SQRT( ' ||
                                                'Case ' ||
                                                    'When( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                                                    'Then( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ' ||
                                                    'Else NULL ' ||
                                                'End ' ||
                                            ') ' ||
                                        ', 3 ) ' ||
                                    ', 0 ) ' ||
                                ') ' ||
                            'Else NULL ' ||
                        'End ) ' ||
                    '/ ' ||
                    'LOG( 2 ) ' ||
                ') ' ||
                ') ' ||
                '/* Log_2 (x) = Log_10 (x) / Log_10 (2) */ AS "Doane" ' ||
                ', ( ' ||
                    'Cast( 3.49 AS Float ) ' ||
                    '* ' ||
                    'SQRT( ' ||
                        'Case ' ||
                            'When ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) >= 0 ' ||
                            'Then ( "Sum x2" - ( "N" * "Avgx 2" )) / NULLIF( NULLIF( "N-1", 0 ), -1 ) ' ||
                            'Else NULL ' ||
                        'End ' ||
                    ') ' ||
                    '/ ' ||
                'Power( Case When "N" >= 0 Then "N" Else NULL End, ( -1 / Cast( 3 AS Float ))) ' ||
                ') AS "Scott" ' ||
            'From ' ||
            '( ' ||
                'Select ' ||
                    'Cast( COUNT(*) AS Bigint ) AS "N w Null" ' ||
                    ', Cast( COUNT( "'|| col.column_name || '" ) AS Bigint ) AS "N" ' ||
                    ', ( 1 / NULLIF( Cast( COUNT( "'|| col.column_name || '" ) AS Float ), 0 ) ) AS "1/N" ' ||
                    ', Cast( COUNT( "'|| col.column_name || '" ) AS Bigint ) - 1 AS "N-1" ' ||
                    ', MIN( "'|| col.column_name || '") AS "Min" ' ||
                    ', MAX( "'|| col.column_name || '") AS "Max" ' ||
                    ', AVG( "'|| col.column_name || '") AS "Avg" ' ||
                    ', Power( AVG( "'|| col.column_name || '"), 2 ) AS "Avgx 2" ' ||
                    ', Power( AVG( "'|| col.column_name || '"), 3 ) AS "Avgx 3" ' ||
                    ', Power( AVG( "'|| col.column_name || '"), 4 ) AS "Avgx 4" ' ||
                    ', Sum( "'|| col.column_name || '") AS "Sum" ' ||
                    ', Sum( Power( "'|| col.column_name || '", 2 )) AS "Sum x2" /* Also called: "Uncorrected Sum of Squares" */ ' ||
                    ', Sum( Power( "'|| col.column_name || '", 3 )) AS "Sum x3" ' ||
                    ', Sum( Power( "'|| col.column_name || '", 4 )) AS "Sum x4" ' ||
                    ', Cast( COUNT( DISTINCT "'|| col.column_name || '" ) AS Bigint ) AS "Uniq" ' ||
                    ', Cast( Sum( Case When "'|| col.column_name || '" = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End ) AS Bigint ) AS "0" ' ||
                    ', Cast( Sum( Case When "'|| col.column_name || '" > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End ) AS Bigint ) AS "POS" ' ||
                    ', Cast( Sum( Case When "'|| col.column_name || '" < 0 Then 1 Else 0 End ) AS Bigint ) AS "NEG" ' ||
                    ', Cast( Sum( Case When "'|| col.column_name || '" is NULL Then 1 Else 0 End ) AS Bigint ) AS "Null" ' ||
                    ', EXP( AVG( LN( Case When "'|| col.column_name || '"> 0 Then "'|| col.column_name || '" Else NULL End )) ) AS "Geometric Mean" ' ||
                    ', 1 / NULLIF( AVG( 1 / NULLIF(( Case When "'|| col.column_name || '"> 0 Then "'|| col.column_name || '" Else NULL End ), 0 )), 0 ) AS "Harmonic Mean" ' ||
                'From ' ||
                '( ' ||
                    'Select ' ||
                        'Cast( "'|| col.column_name || '" AS Float ) AS "'|| col.column_name || '" ' ||
                    'From "'|| col.table_schema ||'"."'|| col.table_name ||'" ' ||
                ') t ' ||
            ') t ' ||
        ') t ' AS "TheQuery"
From
    information_schema.columns AS col
Where 1=1
    AND col.data_type IN
    (
          'numeric'
        , 'integer'
        , 'double precision'
        , 'bigint'
        , 'real'
        , 'smallint'
    )
;
```

It is inside this table we are going to filter on the "SchemaName" and "TableName" so that we can run the right subset of queries per columns

**Part 4:**
The Stored Procedure that takes a subset of queries,run them and put the set of resulting rows in the __UNIVARIATE__ result table.

```
DROP FUNCTION If Exists stat.f_udf_sql_trans_trim( col CHARACTER VARYING ) ;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stat.f_udf_sql_trans_trim( col CHARACTER VARYING )
RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN
    TRIM( BOTH E'\\x0D' FROM /* gets rid of CR: 'Carriage Return' special character */
    TRIM( BOTH E'\\x0A' FROM /* gets rid of LF: 'Line Feed' special character */
    TRIM( BOTH E'\\x0B' FROM /* gets rid of vertical TAB: '\v' special character */
    TRIM( BOTH E'\\x09' FROM /* gets rid of horizontal TAB: '\t' special character */
    TRIM( col) ) ) ) )       /* gets rid of Space character: ' ' special character */
;
END ;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
EXTERNAL SECURITY DEFINER
;




Drop Function If Exists stat.f_sp_sql_stat_univariate( CHARACTER VARYING, CHARACTER VARYING) ;
Create Or Replace Function stat.f_sp_sql_stat_univariate( IN sch VARCHAR( 63), IN tbl VARCHAR( 63) )

RETURNS SETOF __UNIVARIATE__ AS

$func$

Declare

    q_row RECORD ;
    ddl VARCHAR := '' ;

Begin

    For q_row IN
        Select
            *
        From
            stat.__QBUILDER_UNIVARIATE__
        Where 1=1
            And "SchemaName" = stat.f_udf_sql_trans_trim( sch )
            And "TableName" = stat.f_udf_sql_trans_trim( tbl )
    Loop
        ddl = 'INSERT INTO __UNIVARIATE__ ' || q_row."TheQuery" ;
        Execute ddl ;
        ddl := '' ;
        Return Query Execute q_row."TheQuery" ;
    End Loop ;
    Return ;

End ;

$func$

LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
EXTERNAL SECURITY DEFINER
;
```

We run the SP:

```
Select * From stat.f_sp_sql_stat_univariate('data','iris') ;
```

PS: In a more global way, do you think it is necessary to have this kind of material for the PG community?

Answer (score 1):

My comments is limited because I know next to nothing about statistics and I admit I don't understand what most of the calculations are supposed to do or how to interpret the results.

That said, you currently use a view which is basically to concatenate a massive string. As it is, it's hard to decode the string. I'd suggest that you create a scalar function or a table to store the template, in a manner akin to this:

```
$$
RETURN '
SELECT
  ....
  ....
  ....
FROM {{@SchemaName}}.{{@TableName}};';
$$
```

That way you eliminate all those `||` concatenation and can easily generate a well-formatted SQL that's still easy to copy'n'paste for testing outside of the stored procedure. You then simply only need to replace the placeholders with the variable you want to use.

I am not sure what this buys you:

```
    Select
        *
    From
        stat.__QBUILDER_UNIVARIATE__
    Where 1=1
        And "SchemaName" = stat.f_udf_sql_trans_trim( sch )
        And "TableName" = stat.f_udf_sql_trans_trim( tbl )
```

I get that people use the `1=1` idiom to make it easy to add predicates in the `WHERE` clause but this isn't dynamic SQL, so you're just adding noise with that predicate. Also I'm not sure what you're intending to accomplish with the function `f_udf_sql_trans_trim`; it seems to me much more efficient to validate that the parameters `sch` and `tbl` in fact exist in the `information_schema`, so we could just do:

```
    WHERE "SchemaName" = sch
      AND "TableName" = tbl
      AND EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM information_schema.tables AS t
        WHERE t.name = tbl
     ) AND EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM information_schema.schemas AS s
        WHERE s.name = sch
     );
```

That way you've taken care of all possible special characters. You might want to do this as a separate query so you can short-circuit if the inputs are invalid.

Finally, your SQL formatting is inconsistent. In some places you use UPPERCASE (e.g. `INSERT INTO`) but in others, you use PascalCase (e.g. `Create Table`). It makes for too much distraction while reading the code.